# Sobrecarga método IActionResult

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy probando a hacer dos `IActionResult`, uno con parámetro de `id` y otro sin él. Quiero que me devuelva distinta cosa en función de si la URL tiene id o no. El problema es que me da el siguiente error

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

Quisiera saber por qué y si es que el método IActionResult no se puede sobrecargar así, muchas gracias. Pongo un código de ejemplo para aclarar el texto

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Prueba sin id");
    }

    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return Content("Prueba con id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta que sobrecargues el metodo, puede validar si es vacio o no el parametro y tomar alguna accion.

La Sobre carga de los metodos se puede realizar dandole una accion diferente a cada ActionResult, por defecto es GET y puedes sobrecargarlo si necesitas hacerlo POST para recibir algo.

```
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    if(id == 0)
    {
     //mostrar una vista
    return Content("Prueba sin id");

    }
    else
    {
     // Mostrar otra vista
    return Content("Prueba con id");

    }

}
[HttPost]
public IActionResult Index(Modelo id)
{
    if(id == null)
    {
     //mostrar una vista
    return Content("Prueba sin id");

    }
    else
    {
     // Mostrar otra vista
    return Content("Prueba con id");

    }

}
```

Comment: Entonces, si he entendido bien, ¿solo se pueden tener dos métodos sobrecargados de `IActionResult`? ¿Los parámetros no influyen para la sobrecarga de este método? Estoy aprendiendo sobre MVC en c# y la pregunta es más por saber del tema que por resolver un problema concreto. Gracias

Comment: Depende del Action Http, tenes Get, Put, Delete, Post y Path (actualizacion parcial)